# How to punch holes through overlaying div by applying canvas as a mask with CSS

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I have drawn a canvas with the following content:

[image]

How do I correctly set the canvas as a clipping mask in CSS for an entire div?

This is my code:

```js
var punchHole = function(x, y, r, ctx){
    ctx.save()
    ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    ctx.clip()
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    ctx.restore();
}

function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('splash-canvas').getContext('2d');
    var circles = [{x: 50, y: 50, r: 50}, {x: 75, y: 75, r: 50}];
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    for (var i=0; i<circles.length; i++){
        punchHole(circles[i].x, circles[i].y, circles[i].r, ctx)
    }
}
window.onload = draw;
```

```css
.aside, .content, canvas{
  left:0;
  top:0;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
}
.content{
  z-index:2;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;
  background:yellow;
}
.aside{
  color:green;
  z-index:3;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: block;
  mask: url(#splash-canvas);
}
canvas{
  z-index:5;
}
.hidden{
  overflow:hidden;
  width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hidden"><canvas id="splash-canvas"  width="150" height="150"></canvas></div>
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="aside">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

As can be seen the canvas is applied as a mask, but it also shown itself and hides the content in the layer it masks. Not sure what I am doing wrong. What I'd expect to happen is that the black region should be replaced with the content of the `.aside` layer (green text), and the content of the `.content` layer (red text) should be visible through the hole (this already happens). I've tried storing the canvas inside a hidden div (overflow:hidden), but no dice. I've also tried hiding the canvas behind everything else on the screen, but it still shows on top.

Comment: *As can be seen the canvas is applied as a mask* --> it's not applied as mask. Where did you read that you can apply a canvas as mask? this is not doable

Comment: I've never worked with canvas before, however, in my example there are 3 layers: 1. red text, 2. green text, 3. canvas (mask).
There is a hole in the mask. I can clearly see layer 1 through it, however I cannot see the intermediate layer, therefore I conclude the mask has been applied to layer 2. Otherwise I should see the green text overlapped on the red one. CSS mask uses alpha information to decide what is visible and what is not and the canvas in this case clearly has alpha information.

Comment: remove the mask property and you will see the same result (mask is doing nothing here). overflow:hidden is doing nothing because canvas is position:absolute. Either remove position:absolute or add position:relative to its parent element

Comment: you are right about the overflow hidden issue. however here is a screenshot with mask disabled vs enabled: https://imgur.com/a/OZqh0J0 there is definitely something happening, but not what I expected.

Comment: use `mask:url(#qsdqsdq)` (a random string as ID) and you will have the same result. You cannot use canvas as mask, the property is ignoring that value and is falling back to transparent. ID inside mask is to reference an SVG

Comment: I have tested and you are correct. I think all your comments could be compiled into a good answer to the question. If you care to do that I'll mark it as a solution. Knowing there is no solution is as good to know as the proper existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need all that amount of code or canvas. What you want can be achieved with a background coloration using gradients.

```css
.content{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:30px;
  color:#0000;
  background:                                   /* position */
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 98%,#0000) 20px  20px,
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,red 98%,#0000) 160px 100px,
   green;
  background-size:200px 200px; /* size of the circles */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-clip:text;
          background-clip:text;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: sorry, my snippet was just to prove the concept. what I am trying to achieve is to dissolve the upper layer so that the layer behind can be seen. this is what I am trying to reproduce: https://imgur.com/swm6ifG ,  so basically I wanted to work with canvas to animate the mask. 
I cannot accept this answer, as it does not answer the question.